# XPaths are not working in XSLT global functions

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have implemented the following xslt global function, but it is not allowing to use XPath expressions.

For Example: //Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/Begin_Adjacent_Track_ID !='' is throwing exception.

```
            <xsl:function name="conn:getConnetion" as="xs:string">
                   <xsl:param name="TYPE" as="xs:string"/>
                   <xsl:param name="TrackID" as="xs:string"/>
                   <xsl:param name="SwitchID" as="xs:string"/>    
                   <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="($TYPE = 'TrackBegin')">
                            <xsl:if test="((//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/Begin_Adjacent_Track_ID !='') and (//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/Begin_Adjacent_Track_ID !='0'))"> 
                              <xsl:sequence select="concat(concat((TrackID * 10000) , '#'), (concat((//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/Begin_Adjacent_Track_ID * 10000), 1)))"/>
                            </xsl:if>               
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="($TYPE = 'TrackEnd')">            
                            <xsl:if test="((//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/End_Adjacent_Track_ID !='') and (//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/End_Adjacent_Track_ID !='0'))"> 
                              <xsl:sequence select="concat(concat(concat((TrackID * 10000) , 1) , '#'), (//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/End_Adjacent_Track_ID * 10000))"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <!-- <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise> -->
                   </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:function>
```

Could you please let us know if our implementation is having any issues.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no context node or context item in a function, thus, if you want to access nodes from a certain document, you will need to define an `xsl:param` for that document or node and pass it in in the function call e.g.

```
        <xsl:function name="conn:getConnetion" as="xs:string">
               <xsl:param name="TYPE" as="xs:string"/>
               <xsl:param name="TrackID" as="xs:string"/>
               <xsl:param name="SwitchID" as="xs:string"/> 
               <xsl:param name="track-doc" as="document-node()"/>   
               <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="($TYPE = 'TrackBegin')">
                        <xsl:if test="(($track-doc//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/Begin_Adjacent_Track_ID !='') and ($track-doc//Track_Chainings/Track_Chaining[Track_ID=$TrackID]/Begin_Adjacen
          ....
```

and then call the function with the right document e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="conn:getConnection('foo', 't1', 's2', /)"/>`